# Question about an example procedure to obtain a basis from L.I list in Axler's Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

In the Bases section of the book there is an example that says:

*As an example in $F^3$ suppose we start with the linearly independent list $\{(2,3,4),(9,6,8)\ \} \rightarrow (\alpha)$. If we take
$w_1,w_2,w_3$ in the proof to be the standard basis of $F^3$ then the procedure produces the list $(2,3,4),(9,6,8),(0,1,0)$ which is a basis of $F^3$*

**Step 1**

*If $v_1=0$, delete it from B. If $v_1 \neq 0 $, leave B unchanged*.

**Step j**

*If $v_j$ is in $span(v_1,...,v_{j-1})$ delete $v_j$ from B. If $v_j$ is not in the span, leave B unchanged*.

*Applying the procedure above to the list $u_1,...,u_m,w_1,...,w_n$  (u's are l.i and w's are basis of $V$) to reduce this list to a basis of V produces a list of the vectors $u_1,...u_m$ (none of the us get deleted because they are L.I) and some of the w's.*

The problem is that, I do not know where the vector $\mathbf{(0,1,0)}$ came from (I cannot assume using it directly in the definitions, there must be an origin since proposing immediately $(1,0,0)$ or $(0,0,1)$ may be a waste of time).

So I know that ($\alpha$) is linearly independent and the steps above tells us that a vector $v_j$ might be in the $span(v_1,...,v_{j-1})$.

In the section of span, *the set of all linear combinations of a list of vectors $v_{1},...,v_{m}$ in $V$ is called the span of $v_{1},...,v_{m}$*.

Then, I proceeded to solve the system:

(Taking $(9,6,8)$ as the $v_{jth}$ vector)

$(9,6,8)=a_1(2,3,4)+a_2(9,6,8)$

Resulting in:

$a_1=0$ and  $a_2=1$,

and taking $a_3=0$ generates the vector $(0,1,0)$

The procedure tells us not to delete the rest of the vectors in $\alpha$, because they are L.I, and now with the added vector it fulfills the definition of a basis.

So my final question is:

Is my procedure (reasoning) right?

Is there another way to obtain that vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a much more efficient way. Consider the vectors as columns; you add to the given linearly independent vectors a known basis of the space (whatever you like, not necessarily the standard one). With the standard basis you get
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 9 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
4 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
and perform Gaussian elimination:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 9 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
4 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 9/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
4 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_1\gets \tfrac{1}{2}R_1 \\[6px]
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 9/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -15/2 & -3/2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -10 & -2 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&& \begin{aligned}R_2&\gets R_2-3R_1 \\ R_3&\gets R_3-4R_1\end{aligned}\\[6px]
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 9/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1/5 & -2/15 & 0 \\
0 & -10 & -2 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_2\gets-\tfrac{2}{15}R_2 \\[6px]
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 9/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1/5 & -2/15 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -4/3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_3\gets R_3+10R_2
\end{align}
You see that the fourth column becomes the third pivot column. And you knew at the outset that the matrix has rank $3$.

This means that columns 1, 2 and 4 are linearly independent *in all* the previously written matrices, because elementary row operations don't change the linear relation among columns. In particular, the first two columns will *necessarily* be pivot column in the elimination.

We conclude that columns 1, 2 and 4 in the initial matrix are linearly independent.

No need to test the vector in the “adjoined” basis one by one, because you can do it at once.

Comment: I was trying not to use matrices to get there, only the information covered so far in the book to that chapter. But many thanks, that is way more efficient.

Comment: @1239308 And there is an even more efficient way if the vector space can be equipped with a nondegenerate bilinear form (the inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$, for instance), because you can use an easy to compute complement.